Why remote SQL Server is not accepting connections without user logged into the server
We have an SSIS Server and a Database server. SSIS Package unable to connecting to remote SQL Server while running the package, however, it works fine when someone is logged into the server.
Extended events shows the error 10054. Most of the troubleshooting taken into consideration as per the MS article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-exist-connection-closed
Why this is working when someone from the DBA team has a RDP session.
Also, Firewall logs shows traffic against RDP user instead of SSIS Caller account which runs the package. Network team told there is no traffic from the user.

I replaced the  tag with , since this isn't related to the SQL language.

The account on the SSIS server running the package probably not set correctly or does not have permissions to the database or server.  Or the firewall is not open for the SSIS server to hit the DB server.

"Expended events showing error as 10054" Which is what? Please actually give us the error, not the number.

What did you actually install on the "SSIS Server"?  You would normally have an instance of the DbEngine to host the SSIS catalog and SQL Agent, as well as the SSIS feature.

SSIS Server includes DB Engine, SSIS & Agent. SSIS Package run by mainframe scheduler. It had ssis admin permissions on catalog . As i informed earlier, it works pefect when someone from DBA team RDP into the box. Once DBA login for the day , It continue for the day and fails for next day . We dont understand what is killing every 24 hrs on this box.

What is the output of SELECT @@VERSION when executed against the problem server?

And what data sources are the SSIS packages using?  These could load third-party drivers and could conceivably interact with an active desktop session.

It's OLEDB Native client. Both sources returning server names
